# Pass parameters to my thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm using c++

I have a thread function 'my_thread', that needs to receive some object (MyParam) as parameter somehow.

I'm not really sure how to pass ownership of the parameter.

Who should be responsible to release it, and at which stage?

What I usually do is this:

```
MyThread::MyThread(func_to_execute, void* param);

void my_thread(MyParam* param)
{
    // Take ownership
    std::unique_ptr<MyParam> obj(param);
    ...
}

void main()
{
    // Create the param. Prepare p
    std::unique_ptr<MyParam> p(new MyParam(...));

    // Create the new thread
    MyThread(my_thread, (void*)param.get());
    // If the creation of the thread succeeded (no exception was thrown), Let go of ownership.
    (void)param.release();
}
```

(I can't use std::thread)

This code assumes that if the ctor of MyThread didn't throw - the thread probably took ownership of it's parameter.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: `Who should be responsible to release it, and at which stage?` -> that's for you to define. There's no rule set in stone.

Comment: Thought about having your thread being owned by a particular class, and passing `this` as parameter to the thread function already? (That's one of the preferred patterns I'm using actually)

Comment: Wrap it in a `std::shared_ptr`, and use `std::thread` which makes it easy to pass arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Ensure that the thread successfully took ownership of p before releasing it in the calling thread.  It's hard to tell if your code is doing that without a MCVE.

Comment: Moby- How do you suggest doing it? Any way I try, is prone to some other failure or race

Comment: It is always preferred do delete in the same place you allocate. You can wait for your thread in the main. and after the thread was done, delete the parameter.

Comment: As far as I understood, MyThread constructor is executed in the main thread and may throw an exception. In this case add a parameter of type std::unique_ptr<MyParam>& to the constructor.